# In SharePoint 2013 is it possible to change the size of modal popup which opens when loading new/edit/display form of all lists?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog

In SharePoint 2013 is it possible to change the size of modal popup which opens when loading new/edit/display form of all lists? I want to inc the width and height.

Please guide..

Comment: I would advise against this, as the only consistent way for this to me seems to edit the built-in javascript that does this. if you were talking about opening modal dialogs for custom pages / buttons, sure, that's just setting a parameter in the SharePoint API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes, but not in a supported way.

All SharePoint Modal Dialog should automatically resize itself based on:

- The size of the browser
- The size of the source page it is displaying (with scrollbars if required)

In my experience you only need to define fixed width / height for your own custom dialogs (and even then it suggests the HTML you are placing in the dialog isn't formatted correctly if you are fixing the width and height in the dialog code)